# how to select image in one class and display it on image view on other class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i am using a button to select an image from gallery and the image will be set to imageview which is on other screen:

**//setimg button is on firstscreen.xml**

```
setimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}   
    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();

             int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
             String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             cursor.close();

             // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image

                ImageView iv_wallset = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_wallset);
                iv_wallset.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
         }
}
```

}

**// Imageview iv_wallset is on second.xml**

can we use intent.putextra() to carry image from one screen to other???

Comment: Yeah . Use putextra() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put an extra String in the intent and from the second activity get the argument and decode the picture:

in activity 1:

```
mIntent.putExtra("image_path", picturePath);
```

in activity 2:

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_path");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_wallset);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes convert image into byte array and pass that byte array to other activity.